# How to normalize only continuous variables in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, normalization

I'm trying to normalize the continuous variables from my dataframe but I'm getting the following error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'M'
```

I know that the error occurs because I have some categorical variables so how can I ignore the categorical variables.
This is my code

```
X=data
mms=MinMaxScaler()
mms.fit(X)
Xnorm=mms.transform(X)
print(Xnorm.min(axis=0))
print(Xnorm.max(axis=0))
print(Xnorm.shape)
```

Comment: Select the columns you want to normalize instead of using all columns. Something like `X = data[['col1', 'col2']]`.

Comment: @matias but that way isn't the dataset reduzed to only that columns?

Comment: No, only variable `X`.

Comment: @matias but if I want to normalize in the dataset I need to normalize in data not in X.

Answer (score 4):

Select the numerical columns, then apply min-max transformation and store the result back into selected numerical columns

```
X = data.select_dtypes(np.number)
data[X.columns] = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(X)
```

Comment: @Subham Sharma I'm getting only 0's and 1's. 
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. nan  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0. nan]
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. nan  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.
  1.  1.  1.  1. nan]
It's normal?

Comment: @P.Brito This depends on your input data, btw what is the shape of input dataframe `data.shape`?

Comment: this is the shape of the data (60398, 64)

Comment: @P.Brito What's the version of `scikit-learn` you are using? Also check the shape of `X`?